# Windows service - cannot see created files

Tags: c#, file, service

I install a windows service using installutil and the project installer Account property is set to User.

I install the service as the user who is currently logged on (domain/username).

The service does some stuff and creates a text file. I cannot see the text file in windows explorer but I know it is there based on the output of the service.

If I am logged in as the user who is running the service why can I not see the files the service creates?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the current working directory for services defaults to the system folder instead of the folder where the entry assembly is located. Check for the file here. If you want to change the working directory you can do so in code as follows.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
Environment.CurrentDirectory = assemblyFolder;
```

Comment: I was aware that the cwd for services was system32 folder, so i changed the code which creates files to save them in a handcoded path (just for a quick test). The file is still not listed in explorer. I will see if your code makes a difference.